# Custom proxy server headers with .NET Framework HttpWebRequest using C#

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, http-headers, httpwebrequest

I am using the [HttpWebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.8) class to implement a web crawler. I would like to use a proxy server with it which usually can be implemented like this:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.example.com/");          

webRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyUrl, proxyPort);
webRequest.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(proxyPassword, proxyPassword);

HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
using (Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

However, I need to submit an additional parameter to the proxy server. Because the target site uses HTTPS, the parameters must be submitted in the initial CONNECT request that establishes the secure HTTPS tunnel. Otherwise the proxy server is unable to read them due the end-to-end encryption.

The header for the initial CONNECT request should look like this:

```
CONNECT example.com:443 HTTP/1.1
X-CustomProperty: 12345
```

So far I was unable to find a solution to achieve this with neither the [HttpWebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.8) nor the [WebClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.8) class from the .NET Framework. Is there any option to pass additional headers in the initial CONNECT request? I am also happy with a solution that uses an additional library.